# laravel: passing array from view to subview

Tags: php, laravel, view, subview

here's my startcontroller.php:

```
$content = array(
"foo" => "bar"
);
return view("start/start", $content);
```

here's my start view:

```
@include('start/header', array( "foo" => $foo))
echo $foo; // returns "bar"
```

as you can see, i'm passing the foo variable to my subview `header`

my question: is it possible to pass the whole $content variable to the subview? 
i've tried

```
@include('start/header', $content)
```

but i'm getting an error that $content is not defined, so i'd need to access the "default" array which is passed to the start view, any idea if this is possible?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The only option is to pass it to the parent on the first place

```
$data = array(
    'content' = array(
        'foo' => 'bar'
    )
);


return view("start/start", $data);
```

Then in your view

```
@include('start/header', array( "foo" => $content['foo']))
```

Comment: Is this stil valid in 5.8? Actually subview inherit root view's data

Comment: Do you have any reference for that @realtebo ?

Comment: It's in the doc. Since 5.1. This is the link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade . The point of the page is at subtitle "Including Sub-Views", the first paragraph says " All variables that are available to the parent view will be made available to the included view:" - At today, this is the link for the 5.8: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#including-sub-views